# Разница между List[Optional[str]] и Iterable[str]

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

Установил `mypy` и при анализе строчки кода `",".join(ids[:50])`

```
ids: List[Optional[str]] = ["text","test"]
error: Argument 1 to "join" of "str" has incompatible type "List[Optional[str]]"; expected "Iterable[str]"
```

Почему это ошибка? Разве список не итерируемый объект? Какая разница между списком и `Iterable` и в каких случаях что выбирать?

Comment: в Python итератор - это объект, реализующий интерфейс итератора, который состоит из методов __iter __ () и __next __ () а список не имеет этих методов.

Comment: @DaniilLoban, есть разница между итератором (Iterator) и итерируемым объектом (Iterable). Список является итерируемым объектом.

Comment: если подходить к вопросу технически то список не является итерируемым, во всяком случае это не указано в [спецификации](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/list.html) списка, по большому счету если он может использоваться в цикле for еще не значит что он итерируемый изначально, например [тут](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) написано `Оператор for выполняет итерацию по элементам любой последовательности (списка или строки) в том порядке, в котором они появляются в последовательности. `

Comment: @DaniilLoban, см. [Iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable): `An object capable of returning its members one at a time. **Examples of iterables include all sequence types (such as list, str, and tuple)** and some non-sequence types like dict, file objects, and objects of any classes you define with an __iter__() method or with a __getitem__() method that implements Sequence semantics.` И ниже отдельно есть Iterator. По сути, любой итератор - Iterable, любой sequence объект - Iterable. Обратное верно не всегда (не всякий итерируемый объект - итератор, например)

Comment: @DaniilLoban и демонстрация в коде: `isinstance(list(), Iterable)` вернет True, `isinstance(list(), Iterator)` вернет False, так что вполне можно указывать Iterable как обобщение для типа List.

Comment: @DaniilLoban, да, и по поводу вашего изначального утверждения, см. [`collections.abc.Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable): `ABC for classes that provide the __iter__() method.`, [`collections.abc.Iterator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterator): `ABC for classes that provide the __iter__() and __next__() methods.`. У списка есть метод `__iter__`, и он является `Iterable` (на этом заканчиваю, не интересно спорить в одну сторону :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве ответа вопрос:"Какая разница между списком и Iterable и в каких случаях что выбирать?" можно привести пример,

```
class MyNumbers:
  def __iter__(self):
    self.a = 1
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    if self.a <= 20:
      x = self.a
      self.a += 1
      return x
    else:
      raise StopIteration

myclass = MyNumbers()

for x in myclass:
  print(x)
```

В результате выполнения мы получим числа от 1 до 20. `myclass` является итерируемым объектом, в то же время он генерирует свои значения во время исполнения, в отличие от списка который всегда сформирован. Список имеет в себе итератор, как и строка, они возвращают его с помощью метода `iter()` таким образом мы получаем разницу между списком и итератором:

`list != iter(list)`

Answer (score 5):

Проблема не в `List`/`Iterable`, а в `Optional`. `List[Optional[str]]` подразумевает то, что список может содержать строки или `None`, но `join` не умеет соединять значения `None`, требуемый тип принимаемого значения у него - `Iterable[str]`, т.е. итерируемый объект из строк (строго из строк, никаких `None`). Если убрать `Optional`, то ошибка исчезнет.

Пример кода:

```
from typing import List


ids: List[str] = ["text","test"]
print(", ".join(ids))
```

Вывод mypy:

```
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

mypy на `Optional` ругается не просто так: ваша аннотация предполагает, что возможен список такого вида `["text", None]`, при применении `join` к которому вылетит ошибка `TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, NoneType found`.

Comment: Оба ответа на вопрос отлично обьясняют тему. Спасибо